# Capistrano puma jobs does nothing

Tags: capistrano, puma, capistrano3

I am trying to perform some puma actions using cap, and it does nothing.

For example:

```
cap production puma:config
```

This is my deploy.rb:

```
lock '3.10.1'

set :application, 'AppName'
set :repo_url, '########@git.......' # Edit this to match your repository
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] if ENV['BRANCH']
set :user, 'root'
set :deploy_to, '/home/root/AppName'
set :pty, true
#set :linked_files, %w{config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.1'

set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"   #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "/home/root/GlucoMeDDC/current/config/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [1, 1]
set :puma_workers, 3
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, true

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke! 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
include SSHKit::DSL
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Workers
require 'sshkit'
require 'sshkit/dsl'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets' # for asset handling add
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations' # for running migrations

# require 'capistrano/rbenv'

require 'capistrano/ssh_doctor'
require 'capistrano/yarn'

# Include default deployment tasks

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require "capistrano/scm/git-with-submodules"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git::WithSubmodules
# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
# require "capistrano/bundler"
# require "capistrano/rails/assets"
# require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Returns nothing, just empty row.

Capistrano.log:

```
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO START 2018-01-18 16:30:55 +0200 cap production puma:config
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tasks list:

```
cap puma:config          # Setup Puma config file
cap puma:halt            # halt puma
cap puma:make_dirs       # Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket
cap puma:phased-restart  # phased-restart puma
cap puma:restart         # restart puma
cap puma:start           # Start puma
cap puma:status          # status puma
cap puma:stop            # stop puma
cap puma:workers:count   # Add a worker
cap puma:workers:less    # Worker--
cap puma:workers:more    # Worker++
```

Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: You are right.
Added few important details such as deploy.rb and my Capfile.

Comment: From these files, I don't see the `puma:config` task defined.

Comment: puma:config task is task comes together with capistrano-puma gem, I don't have to define it.

Comment: You are missing `deploy/$enviroment.rb` config. I just encountered same issue, and I've got some guesses. Maybe our issues related.